Запуск сервиса Minecraft Server
Пытаюсь сделать автозапуск майнкрафт сервера на debian 12 через ExecStart.
В итоге это не получается максимум что можно добиться это ошибки 203 и 127, причем если запустить start.sh из терминала то все работает!
Description="MinecraftServer"
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/home/cooktyan/Server/Minecraft Forge 164/start.sh"
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target``` 



А скрипту start.sh точно пофиг на текущий рабочий каталог? Несовпадение текущих рабочих каталогов в терминале и в systemd вполне может вызывать проблемы, если скрипт не рассчитан на такое

Все таки получилось сделать автозапуск но к сожалению окошка стандартного от java сервера увидеть не получается (как и терминала, все работает в скрытом режиме)
Скрипт сервера выглядит так:
Description="MinecraftServer"
[Service]
ExecStart=sudo -u cooktyan -s /home/cooktyan/Server/MinecraftForge164/StartServer.sh
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target```

Start.sh выглядит так:

```#!/bin/bash
cd /home/cooktyan/Server/MinecraftForge164 
java -jar MinecraftServer.jar -Xms1G -Xmx4G server.jar```

ServerStart.sh как прослойка (пытался консоль вывести, в сервисе можно просто заменить на Start.sh)



Вместо sudo лучше используйте User=cooktyan
